# Convergence of a series of operators $(A_nx)(t)$ = $\int_{1/n}^{1-1/n}k(t,s)x(s)ds$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $A_n$ be a sequence of operators on a $A_n \in B(C[0,1])$ where C[0,1] is continuous functions defined on [0,1] and B(C[0,1]) is [Banach space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_algebra).

$(Ax)(t)=\int_{1/n} ^{1-1/n} k(s,t) x(s)ds$,
where $k(t,s)$ is a continuous function on the square $[0,1]^2$

I want to define type of convergence and find limit in space.

My attempt:
$A_n: C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$
$\left \| A_nx \right \|_{C[0,1]}\leq \int_{1/n}^{1-1/n}\left | k(t,s) \right |\left | x(s) \right |ds \leq \int_{1/n}^{1-1/n}\left | k(t,s) \right |$ since $ \left | x(s) \right | \leq 1$
So $\left \| A_n \right \| = \int_{1/n}^{1-1/n}\left | k(t,s) \right |ds$.

Any help are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$(Ax)(t)=\int\limits_0^1K(s,t)x(s)\,ds$$
Then $\|A_n-A\|\to 0.$ Indeed
$$(Ax)(t)-(A_nx)(t)=\int\limits_0^{1/n}K(s,t)x(s)\,ds+\int\limits_{1-1/n}^1K(s,t)x(s)\,ds$$
Hence
$$|(Ax)(t)-(A_nx)(t)|\le \int\limits_0^{1/n}|K(s,t)||x(s)|\,ds+ \int\limits_{1-1/n}^1|K(s,t)||x(s)|\,ds\\
\le {2\over n}\|K\|_\infty \|x\|_\infty$$
Thus
$$\|Ax-A_nx\|_\infty \le {2\over n}\|K\|_\infty \|x\|_\infty$$
which implies
$$\|A_n-A\|\le {2\over n}\|K\|_\infty$$

Comment: Thanks. Pls, can you clarify how we get this $|(Ax)(t)-(A_nx)(t)|\le {2\over n}\|K\|_\infty \|x\|_\infty$?

Comment: Is it clearer now ? I have used the fact $\int\limits_a^b|f(x)|\,dx\leq (b-a)\|f\|_\infty.$